# Collecting console logs

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I have been working to come up with a proposal to renew our observability solution where I work.
For this purpose, i have proposed that we use OTEL and the OTEL collector - to send the data to where we store/visualise it.

One concern that has been raised by the team responsible for our k8s cluster is "how do we get logs if an application fails before they can be send to the collector".

Right now we have an agent that collect logs from stdout and stderr from the pods, so even if a pod fails very early the logs are printed to the console and collected.

But if we switch to a solution where we send all our observability data to the OTEL collector, how would i ensure that we can catch this?

E.g
*During start up of the application, the configuration is passed to a validator. This validation fails, so the application crashes.
But because it is during validation of the configuration the exception is just shown in the console.*

How can this be collected? Keeping in mind the application is running in a container in a pod.

I have not see any mention of this in the documentation on the opentelemetry site. And looking through the list of receivers in the [collector contrib repo](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver).

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?